# error while parsing JSON file, probally a hidden value on the JSON content

Tags: python, node.js, json, go

I have this JSON file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zh_fJJNWs9GaPnlLZ459twSubsYkzMi5/view?usp=share_link

Looks normal at first, even using online **json schema validators**
However when parsing it locally, I get error.
I tried it with python, nodejs and golang but It's not working.
I think it probably has some hidden value that make impossible to parse it

Comment: would you try this? read as bytes and decode and load!  `#data = json.load(open(file_path)) vs
with open (file_path , "rb") as f:
    data= f.read()
json_data = json.loads(data.decode("utf-16"))
json_data['snaps']`

Comment: @simpleApp right, that worked, how did you know it was utf-16 encoded?

Comment: If you look at a hexdump of the file (e.g, using `xxd` or `od`), you can (a) see the initial [byte order mark](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) and (b) you can see that each character is actually encoded as two bytes.

Comment: utilized the `chardet` module to determine the encoding, deep dive refer @larsks comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the complete solution. comments added against the code.

```
# read the file as bytes
import chardet
import json
file_path=r"2022_2973.json"
with open (file_path , "rb") as f:
    data= f.read() # read file as bytes
file_encoding=chardet.detect(data)['encoding'] # detect the encoding
print(f"file(bytes) encoding:{file_encoding}") # print encoding

json_data = json.loads(data.decode(file_encoding)) # decode the bytes and load the json data
json_data['snaps'][1]
```

output:

```
file(bytes) encoding:UTF-16
{'group': 'Slot',
 'group_order': 1,
 'positions': [{'group': 'Slot',
   'position': 'SLWR',
```