# Trying to load JSON file using either pandas or python

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
import json
with open("https://www.dropbox.com/s/55vqvl1qdsdul8v/publicextract_charity.json?dl=0", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        try:
            json_data = json.loads(line)
            # Process the JSON data here
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
```

json_data
Why does it return:

NameError: name 'json_data' is not defined

Tried to use pd.read_json but I don't know how to handle errors.

Updated link so you can see file.

Entire code:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
df = pd.read_json(
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/55vqvl1qdsdul8v/publicextract_charity.json?dl=0"
, encoding=
'utf-8'
)
```

Returns:

```
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Approach two:

```
import json
with open("/Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/publicextract_charity.json", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        try:
            json_data = json.loads(line)
            # Process the JSON data here
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
json_data
```

The resulting error above.

Comment: What does your file look like?  Usually you'd have a single JSON object in a file rather than one per line.

Comment: I've updated the question so you can see the JSON.

Comment: try this `import json
with open("/Users/xxx/Downloads/publicextract_charity.json", "r",encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
       json_data = json.load(file)`, you need to handle the encoding.

Comment: @simpleApp Thanks you I worked out a solution:

import json 
with open("/Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/publicextract_charity.json", "r",encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = pd.read_json(f)

I now have a dataframe that I can work with.\

Comment: Another one for @simpleApp. Is there a tool for working out encodings? I'd never heard of utf-8-sig.

Comment: glad it worked! pls, refer to this [response from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75253022/error-while-parsing-json-file-probally-a-hidden-value-on-the-json-content/75253495#75253495).

Answer (score 1):

```
import json


with open("publicextract_charity.json", "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)

json_data
```